# Configure app to deploy to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I posted a question earlier today here [Heroku deploy problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137707/advice-needed-please-is-this-a-correct-directory-structure-for-a-flask-app).

I've had a lot of good suggestions, but could not get my app to deploy on Heroku.

I have stripped the app to 15 lines of code. The app still refuses to deploy.

This is the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'main'
File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(run())
WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
```

This is my app's directory:

[image]

This is the content of the `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn main:app --log-file=-
```

This is the content of the main.py file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

@app.route('/')
def hello():
   return 'Hello World!'

 if __name__ == '__main__':
# REMEMBER: Never have this set to True on Production
# manager.run()
  app.run()
```

I have followed all the tutorials, read up on modules and packages, saw suggestions on this site, read Explore Flask, and The Official Flask documentation. They ALL have some sort of variation of establishing an app and its very difficult to understand what is the right way or where files are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your example code:

1. You need a package.

> No module named 'main'

in the proc file, you said: `web: gunicorn main:app --log-file=-`. The right way is add a `__init__.py` beside the `main.py`, so python knows that is a package. Edit your proc file to this:

```
web: gunicorn blackduckflock.main:app --log-file=-
```

2. The instance folder.

Since you specify `instance_relative_config=True`, I think the proper way to organize your project like this:

```
blackduckflock
├── blackduckflock
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
├── config.py
├── instance
│   └── config.py
└── Procfile
```

And you can run `gunicorn blackduckflock.main:app` to see if it works.